# Disable horizontal scrolling on input type text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have input text that is readonly and it might contain long text. I'm trying with css to disable user to scroll horizontally with mouse but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried overflow: hidden; with input text. I also tried setting a fix width for the input. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution which is great using div that is editable and disabling the horizontal scroll on it. This is the code for it:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
I'm Editable. And you can't scroll me!I'm Editable. And you can't scroll me!I'm Editable. And you can't scroll me!I'm Editable. And you can't scroll me!I'm Editable. And you can't scroll me!
</div>
```

CSS

```css
div{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the `<textarea>` tag is more accurate for long text.

maybe something like this can help you:

```css
textarea{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea>
    Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello 
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Edit: 
On input read only you can use the pointer-events: none
see:

```css
input{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/zecka/pen/KKKxrBv

Comment: That works. But for input field I think there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

solved in react application.
this is what I have tried for disabling horizontal scroll on input element. instead of 'wheel' event I have relied on 'scroll' event.
in following situation, when input element have larger string and it is in non editing state, user tries to scroll using laptop touch pad input element scrolls because of dynamic width of my column.
using 'scrollLeft' property we can avoid scroll behavior. but this affects editing of input text. using actual width of content we can reset reset the scrollLeft property

```
 const StringCell= ({
    value = '',
    inputRef,
}) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState(value);
    const update = useCallback(
        event => {
            setText(event.target.value);
        },
        [setText]
    );


    const onScrollHandler = useCallback((event) => {
        if(document.activeElement === event.target){
            event.preventDefault();
            if(!event.target.scrollLeft){
                const targetRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
                if(targetRect?.width){
                    event.target.scrollLeft = Math.ceil(targetRect?.width);
                }
            }
        } else {
            event.target.scrollLeft = 0;
        }
        return false;
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
        setText(value);
        const currElem = inputRef?.current;
        currElem?.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler, {passive:false});
        return () => {
            currElem?.removeEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler)
        }
    }, [value]);

    

    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            ref={inputRef}
            title={title}
            value={text}
            onChange={update}
        />
    );
};
```